# Converting SQL Server Date Format from Rails Query

Tags: sql-server, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to complete the following query:

```
@articles = Article.("created_at = ?", Date.today)
```

The `created_at` column is in the following format in the database: `2018-04-20 10:09:41.413`.

I need to be able to remove timestamp from the `created_at` so that I can successfully complete the query. (So that the `created_at` query returns only `2018-04-20`) I tried converting it to only the date but it just returns all the entries.

```
@articles = Article.("CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) = ?", Date.today)
```

I'm using the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` in Rails 5/Ruby 2.5 connected to an Azure SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make the change to what you are querying against instead?

```
@articles = Article.where(created_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..DateTime.now.end_of_day)
```

or

```
@articles = Article.("created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_day)
```

`DateTime.now.beginning_of_day`
Then you will capture all records that were created during the day.

Comment: Happy to help. Do be aware though that you timezones will become an issue. A user in Malaysia will wonder why an article they wrote today isn't showing up.